# Windows 10 COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE only takes effect after I exit the program

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to make microemacs do underlining.

The behaviour is that the underlining does not work whilst the program is running but after the program exits the underlining appears.

Why is this and is there a way to make it work?

Example code to demonstrate this is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>


#define SC_CHAR char
#define BG_GREY (BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE)

HANDLE  g_ConsOut;                   /* Handle to the console */

CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;   /* Console information */

void flagerr(const char * fmt)
{ printf(fmt, GetLastError());
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])

{ HANDLE g_ConsIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  if (g_ConsIn < 0)                                     /* INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE */
    flagerr("Piperr %d\n");

/* SetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE, g_ConsIn ); */
  if (0 == SetConsoleMode(g_ConsIn, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT))
    flagerr("PipeC %d\n");

{ HANDLE g_ConsOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( g_ConsOut, &csbiInfo );
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(g_ConsOut, BG_GREY);

{ int len = csbiInfo.dwSize.X * csbiInfo.dwSize.Y;
  COORD  Coords;
  Coords.Y = 0;
  Coords.X = 0;

{//WORD attr = 0x70 | COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE;        // black on white
  WORD attr = BG_GREY | COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE;      // black on white
  WORD cuf[512];
  int ix;
  for (ix = 512; --ix >= 0; )
    cuf[ix] = attr;

{ SC_CHAR * src = "The Rain in Spain";
  SC_CHAR * blank = "                               ";
  int sl = strlen(src);
  unsigned long n_out;

  FillConsoleOutputAttribute( g_ConsOut, BG_GREY, len, Coords, &n_out );
  FillConsoleOutputCharacter( g_ConsOut, ' ',     len, Coords, &n_out );
  Coords.Y = 0;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition( g_ConsOut, Coords);
  printf("BG_GREY %x US %x A %x\n", BG_GREY, COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE, attr);

  _getch();

  Coords.Y = 1;

  WriteConsoleOutputCharacter( g_ConsOut, blank, strlen(blank), Coords, &n_out );
  WriteConsoleOutputAttribute( g_ConsOut, cuf, sl, Coords, &n_out );
  WriteConsoleOutputCharacter( g_ConsOut, src, sl, Coords, &n_out );
  
  _getch();
  return 0;
}}}}}
```

In Visual Studio 2019

Properties > Advanced > Character Set > Not Set

[image: Character Set]

In the program

[image: In program]

After exiting the program

[image: After Program]

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (by us humans) 1) Please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) consider each '{' or '}' as a separate statement.

Comment: regarding: `register int col;`  There was a time, way back in the early days of C when the modifier `register` meant something.   Today, `register` is treated as a comment and not as a modifier

Comment: why the braces around: `{ int cc = WriteConsoleOutputAttribute( g_ConsOut, cuf, sclen, Coords, &n_out);
  if (cc == 0 || n_out != sclen)
    adb(cc);
  return OK;
}`?

Comment: regarding: `for (col = -1; ++col < sclen; )
    { 
  cuf[col] = attr;`  and all the other references to the variable `col` in this `for()` loop:  In C, a valid index into an array has a valid range of 0...(number of elements in array -1)  I.E. never a negative index.

Comment: what does this function call: `adb(cc);` expected to perform?

Comment: online searches indicate that `scwrite` is part of a scripting language for controlling a `rapid` robot.  and/or it is part of a library for C++, not C

Comment: Hello user3629249,

The braces around are because early versions of C require them.
Currently no early versions of C are being used.

The function adb allows one to detect an error.

The variable col ranges from 0 to sclen -1.

This function is defined here and is not from any libraries.

I am looking for someone who has knowledge of Console windows and knows what special effect is happening here.
This is not really about the code which is doing what it describes.

Comment: @Questaware This would be easier to follow if you took microemacs out of the picture and posted the minimal, complete, self-contained code to reproduce the issue. Also, you should specify what version of Windows 10, and which console you are using ([legacy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/legacymode), new, or [terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/)).

Comment: Hello,

I will work on that.
I am using console legacy.

This is Windows 10 Pro Version 2004.

I use legacy because I want to use Visual Studio 6.0 in order to avoid redistributables.

The problem also occurs with Visual Studio 2019.

The source is on 

www.github.com/questaware/microemacs.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the problem with a standalone program.